# Angular Datatables sorting text inside hyperlink instead of href

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables

I am attempting to sort a column alphanumerically that contains an anchor tag which seems to be 'intercepting' the sort function. It looks like something along the following lines:

```
<tbody>
    <tr><td><a href="/1"></a>Fox</td><tr>
    <tr><td><a href="/2"></a>Cow</td><tr>
    <tr><td><a href="/3"></a>Dog</td><tr>
</tbody>
```

It will return `Fox,Cow,Dog` and `Dog,Cow,Fox` respectively. How do I sort based the content of the `a` tag rather than the text of the `a` tag itself?

```
ctrl.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
    .withOption("order", [
        [1, "asc"]
    ])
    .withOption('paging', false)
    .withOption('searching', false)
    .withOption("sDom", '<"top">rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">');

ctrl.dtColumnDefs = [
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).notSortable(),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1)
];
```

1: Not sortable
2: Alphanumeric (Issue Column)
3-10: Alphanumeric - `td` only has numbers so it sorts fine

Comment: What sort function are you currently using? show us the code.

Comment: @depperm love that, 'Show us the code!'

Comment: edit the question, copy your code, select all of your code and hit a "Ctrl+k" to format(on windows at least, dont know about other systems)

Comment: @depperm any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.withOption('type', 'html')` for the column that contains HTML as follows:

```
ctrl.dtColumnDefs = [
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).notSortable(),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1).withOption('type', 'html')
];
```

From the [documentation](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type):

> `html` - Basic string processing for HTML tags
>
> Sorting - sorted with HTML tags removed
>      Filtering - HTML tags removed from filtering string

See [columns.type](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) for more information.